# I keep getting "maximum recursive updates exceeded" in Vue when using axios and v-for

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api, vue-options-api

I am building an ecommerce site, and I created a component for product-card. I imported that component into the home page so I can display a list of products. I declare a variable of
**products** in the data(){} and also create a beforeMount and put my logic inside it to fetch data using axios.

```
<template>
  <div>
      <section class="new__products"> 
      <div class="container">
        <div class="inner-new-products">
          <home-page-title title-text="New products"></home-page-title>
          <div class="product-cards">
            <product-card
              v-for="(product, index) in products"
              :key="index"
              :product-id="product._id"
              :old-price="product.old_price"
              :new-price="product.new_price"
              :product-image="product.product_image.reverse()[0].url"
              :product-desc="product.product_description"
              :product-name="product.product_name"
            ></product-card>
          </div>
          <!-- :product-link="product.productLink" -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Home",
  components: { ProductCard },
  data() {
     let products: { productId: string, productImage: string, productDesc: string, 
                     newPrice: number, oldPrice: number }[] = [];
     return { products };
  },
  async beforeMount () {
     console.log('Fetching.... ');
     try {
       let response = await net.http.get('/product?page=1&size=7');
       this.products = response.data.message;
     } catch (error) {
       console.log("ERROR: " + error);
     }
  }
});
</script>
```

Everytime I load up the page I keep getting the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Maximum recursive updates exceeded. This means you have a reactive effect that is mutating its own dependencies and thus recursively triggering itself. Possible sources include component template, render function, updated hook or watcher source function.

When I deployed the code to production server, it just crashes as I load the page up. The whole site crashes due to this error, i'm devastated and don't know what to do.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The main problem is using `Array.reverse` in template.

[Reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

> The reverse method transposes the elements of the calling array object in place, mutating the array, and returning a reference to the array.

So whenever the template renders, `products` array (it's elements rather) is changed which triggers another render etc.

Also as the template can (and usually will) be rendered multiple times, applying `reverse` multiple times is probably not what you want.

This types of operations (transforming source data into something to render) are better placed in [computed](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html#computed-properties) (see example bellow - use `productsView` in the template instead of `products`)

Also **do not use `index` as `:key`**. You seem to have `_id` which is probably unique so use it as key instead...

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Home",
  components: { ProductCard },
  data() {
     let products: { productId: string, productImage: string, productDesc: string, 
                     newPrice: number, oldPrice: number }[] = [];
     return { products };
  },
  computed: {
    productsView() {
      return this.products.map(p => ({
        // copy all product properties and add product_image_url
        ...p,
        product_image_url: p.product_image.reverse()[0].url
      }))
    },
  },
  async beforeMount () {
     console.log('Fetching.... ');
     try {
       let response = await net.http.get('/product?page=1&size=7');
       this.products = response.data.message;
     } catch (error) {
       console.log("ERROR: " + error);
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much Michal Levý, you are a blessing . I removed the reverse() and it solved the issue, I'm grateful for you.

Comment: Ideally show an example of it in a computed property please.