# Some pages of Vue Vite app not response after deployed on Godaddy

Tags: vue.js, vite

Some of my pages in **Vue Vite** **are unresponse** after I deployed on **Godaddy** but some pages are working well. but in localhost all pages are working normally, sometimes when I try to wait too long, Chrome shows an error like this (Error code: Out of Memory), I'm trying for several days but I still can't solve it,when I inspect to see in console Vue show a warning like this below:
**Maximum recursive updates exceeded. This means you have a reactive effect that is mutating its own dependencies and thus recursively triggering itself. Possible sources include component template, render function, updated hook or watcher source function.**

Hope someone could help to solve this problem.

Comment: You have to provide more information for anyone to help on this :)

Comment: @LarsNielsen I mean some pages in Vue3 Vite are stuck, I can't do anything when I navigate to that page, except I close the browser Tap, **it happened when I deploy on Godaddy**, but in Localhost it working well.

Comment: To comprehend the situation, we need your pages' code. Something is making a circular dependency. Please share the main parts of your failing pages. Or, check the following link, it may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69057862/i-keep-getting-maximum-recursive-updates-exceeded-in-vue-when-using-axios-and

Comment: @UlvyRomy you have to provide code, explain your configuratio localy and goddady check out [mre]